# how to refresh parent from child window in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I had opened a popup window from a modal now I need to refresh the page where my modal is by closing popup window or by a close button i had tried writing some codes i found here but not working some of my codes are

```js
//this is not working

function closeAndRefresh(){
  opener.location.reload();
  window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call below function on onClose popup/onclick close button

```
function closeAndRefresh() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: still not working maybe my button is not working because when I wrote alert in that function it din't worked

Comment: it's okay I had reloaded it from modal itself I think reloading parent window which contains a modal can't be reloaded from child window

Answer (score 0):

```
function closeAndRefresh() {
    window.top.location.reload();
}
```